# Is the Roblox pathfindingservice outdated?

Tags: lua, roblox

```
local pathFindingService=game:GetService("PathfindingService")
local torso=script.Parent:WaitForChild("Torso")
local human=script.Parent:WaitForChild("Humanoid")

local path=pathFindingService:CreatePath()

path:ComputeAsync(torso.Position, game.Workspace.endingPart.Position)

local waypoints=path:GetWaypoints()

for i, waypoint in pairs(waypoints) do
    if waypoint.Action==Enum.PathWaypointAction.Jump  then
        human:ChangeState(Enum.HumanoidStateType.Jumping)
    end
    human:MoveTo(waypoint.Postion)
    human.MoveToFinished:Wait(2)
end

human:MoveTo(game.Workspace.endingPart.Position)
```

I tried everything removing the part where i think it went wrong but still not working.

Comment: You haven't said what isn't working.

Comment: yea i figured out for some reason it didn't work using r15, but r6 did